# Resharper mark red using statement to use class library in asp.net core

Tags: c#, reference, asp.net-core, using, class-library

[image: see the attached image]

I created class library, created Web Application project, then add reference to the class library in the Web Application project [as explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668164(v=vs.100).aspx), but can't add "using" for it. (the namespace of customer.cs is also "CDemoLib")
(when i added "using CDemoLib;" i got 'cannot resolve symbol CDemoLib'

the code of customer.cs is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CDemoLib
{
 public class Customer
 {
    private int _age;
    private string _name;

    public Customer()
    {
        Age = 0;
        Name = "Not available";
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set { _age = value; }
    }
    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
  }
}
```

[image: reference expanded]

Comment: Well what namespace is declared in `Customer.cs`, which appears to be the only file in `CDemoLib`? Using directives are about namespaces, not assemblies.

Comment: the namespace of customer.cs is also "CDemoLib"

Comment: And is the class public? Please show us the code rather than us having to ask for every little bit of information.

Comment: sorry, code added, class public. any other code?

Comment: No, that looks like it should be fine. And you were able to add the reference with no problems? If you expand the reference, what do you see?

Comment: i just build it with this red, and build passed. also try "new customer()" and build success...

Comment: So what's actually reporting an error? Have you tried disabling plugins such as Resharper?

Comment: you are right, it's resharper...

Comment: I don't know enough about the details of what it doesn't understand to come up with a sensible answer, to be honest. Maybe it doesn't know about .NET Core, or the version you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jon Skeet offer - it look like a Resharper issue. it can compiled, and if i suspend Resharper it fixed...

u can download [new resharper](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+2016.2+EAP) to fix this

Answer (score 5):

Well, `using` doesn't add references to the **assembly**, but to **namespaces** declared in the assembly. The namespaces declared in the assembly may be very different from the assembly file name.

Double click the reference in the solution explorer (the right arrow in your screen shot) to open the "Object Catalog". You will be able to see the namespaces there.

Comment: the namespace of customer.cs is also "CDemoLib"